# Convert WSDL to array

Tags: php, arrays, wsdl, soap-client

I have a WSDL that is mapped to a variable

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("connection_timeout"=>10));
```

It returns an array like:

```
stdClass Object
(
[getProductsReturn] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [barCode] => 5060285475448
                [brandId] => 0
                [childProductIds] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [childProductIdsAsIntArray] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [childProductIdsList] => 
                [fullProductPaths] => Candles->Amber And Lavender Scented Sachet
                [fullProductPathsArray] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [id] => 5883
                [image] => 
                [imageId] => 0
                [itemCount] => 1
                [longDescription] => 
                [masterProductId] => 5883
                [message] => 
                [messagePrice] => 0
                [messageType] => 0
                [optionId] => 0
                [optionName] => null
                [optionSetId] => 0
                [optionSetName] => null
                [orderType] => 5050
                [parentProductCode] => 
                [parentProductId] => 8088
                [price] => 2.99
                [productCode] => AA2485
                [productId] => 0
                [productType] => 1010
                [quantity] => 0
                [quantityPrice] => 0
                [rrp] => 2.99
                [shortDescription] => Amber And Lavender Scented Sachet
                [variation] => 
                [vatCodeDomainId] => 0
                [wrappingPrice] => 0
                [wrappingType] => 0
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [barCode] => 5060285475547
                [brandId] => 0
                [childProductIds] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [childProductIdsAsIntArray] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [childProductIdsList] => 
                [fullProductPaths] => Candles->Lavender And Bergamot Scented Sachet
                [fullProductPathsArray] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [id] => 5881
                [image] => 
                [imageId] => 0
                [itemCount] => 1
                [longDescription] => 
                [masterProductId] => 5881
                [message] => 
                [messagePrice] => 0
                [messageType] => 0
                [optionId] => 0
                [optionName] => null
                [optionSetId] => 0
                [optionSetName] => null
                [orderType] => 5050
                [parentProductCode] => 
                [parentProductId] => 8088
                [price] => 2.99
                [productCode] => AA2484
                [productId] => 0
                [productType] => 1010
                [quantity] => 0
                [quantityPrice] => 0
                [rrp] => 2.99
                [shortDescription] => Lavender And Bergamot Scented Sachet
                [variation] => 
                [vatCodeDomainId] => 0
                [wrappingPrice] => 0
                [wrappingType] => 0
            )
```

I want to show this in a HTML and this is what I had given in the for loop:

```
<pre>
foreach ($product as $products) {
    $currentStockQuantity = $product->barCode($products);
    echo $currentStockQuantity;
    echo $products->barCode;
    echo $products[$i]->shortDescription;
    echo $products[$i]->barCode;
    $i++;
}
```

But it is not showing all the products, there are about 100 products but only one is showing at the moment

Comment: In the code you posted we cannot see the for loop you use so finding the error is not possible at that point. As long as it shows the first element, the concept of displaying data is ok, but your problem seems to be at the loop. Please post the code according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you stored the result array from your WSDL in a `$products` variable, you could try:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->shortDescription;
    echo $product->barCode;
    // ... and whatever you want
}
```

More information about foreach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php